# How I can detect a set of dots is either rhombic or square lattice

Tags: algorithm, opencv, textures, computer-vision

Suppose I have 2D images which contain dots and I can approximately detect each centerpoints of the dots, how I can detect it's either square lattice (square grid) or rhombic (rotated 45 degree)?

[image]

Fortunately my images are regular and not deformed. The rhombic case is actually similar to square but it's only rotated 45 degree. The only issues are:

1. I can detect the circle using hough transform but of course the centerpoints are approximate.
2. The points do not necessarily fill the entire image (see image below)
   [image]

I have been thinking something similar to checkerboard pattern calibration in OpenCV (but of course no camera parameters),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it might be following:

1. Detect the circle using Hough transform but of course the centerpoints are approximate;
2. Choose arbitrary number of points to test. Number of points depends on how accurate you must be / how fast you need to process an image. Multiple points are needed to implement voting to reduce impact of errors. You can use any method to choose points - either complete random or semi random (random with certain point distribution across the image);
3. To detect orientation of grid for each point chosen do nearest neighbor search and find 4 nearest neighbors. Those neighbors will be on edges of the grid lines that goes through particular point. Depending on data-set size you could find neighbors by yourself with two `for` loops or you could use OpenCV `knnSearch` method from FLANN library (Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors);
4. When you have 4 nearest neighbors for each point, you need to determine orientation of lattice at specified point. For that you need to calculate vertical and horizontal distance between each sample point and it's neighbor. If the lattice is squared then Min(deltaX, deltaY) should be close to 0. If it is rhombic, then it will be about half of distance between each two points. Process all the neighbors and make a decision whether lattice it is square or rhombic at this point. Do that for every test point and collect results;
5. Process results and make final decision on lattice orientation depending on votes from each test point.

Comment: neat, definitely will try your approach

Comment: I would recommend a nearest neighbor approach too!

Comment: Mark this as an answer, @Harris's approach is good to, but this one can be extended to detect any orientations, 0, 15, 30, 45,... degree

Answer (score 1):

My approach is little simple, By considering the top two rows , **if centroid of tow dots lies in the same vertical line it square, otherwise rhombic**.  Here you need to do the following steps.

- Find [contours](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) in the image.
- Find centroid for each contour using [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html).
- Now you need to sort centroid in the order of top left to bottom right.
- Take first two row only and check for each centroid in first row to second for  it's x co-ordinates are equal, that is check whether any two points in these rows lies in same vertical line, if so it is square else rhombic.

Also you can refer below C++ code.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int tolerance=3; /// You can varies this to change the result as the centroid may varies in little even if it's lies in same vertical line

///For sorting x,y co-ordinates from top left corner to bottom rgiht corner
struct sort_xy {
    bool operator() (cv::Point pt1, cv::Point pt2) {
         if((pt2.y-tolerance<=pt1.y)&&(pt1.y<=pt2.y+tolerance))  return (pt1.x < pt2.x); ///if y values are equal sort x
        else return (pt1.y < pt2.y); /// else sort y
        }
} compare_xy;



int main(){

Mat tmp,thr;
Mat src=imread("1.png",1);

cvtColor(src,tmp,CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(tmp,thr,10,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);
imshow("thr,",thr);

    ///Find  contours
    vector< vector <Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
    vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;
    int largest_contour_index=0;
    int largest_area=0;
    Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC3,Scalar::all(0)); //create destination image
    findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image

    /// Get the moments and mass centers:
    vector<Moments> _moment(contours.size() );
    vector<Point> centroid( contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ ) {
    _moment[i] = moments( contours[i], false );
    centroid[i] = Point( _moment[i].m10/_moment[i].m00 ,_moment[i].m01/_moment[i].m00 );
    }

    /// Sort centroid of each contour from top left to bottom right
    sort(centroid.begin(), centroid.end(), compare_xy);

    ///Draw  all sorted centroid to dst image
    for( int i = 0; i <centroid.size(); i++ ) {
      circle(dst, centroid[i], 3,Scalar(0,255,0),1,CV_AA, 0);
      imshow("dst",dst);
    }

    /// Store first two rows of centroid to a vector
    vector< vector <Point> > rows(2);
    int j=0;
    for( int i = 0; i < centroid.size(); i++ ) {
    if((centroid[i+1].y-tolerance<=centroid[i].y)&&(centroid[i].y<=centroid[i+1].y+tolerance))
     rows[j].push_back(centroid[i]);
    else j++;
    if(j>1) i = centroid.size();
    }


    /// This block will decide whether the image is Squre or Rhombic.
    /// The loop checks whether any x-coordinates centroid in first row is equal to
    /// x-coordinates centroid in second row, if so it is squre otherwise Rhombic.
    /// That is it simply checks whether two centroid lies in same vertical line.

    int cnt=0;
    if(rows[0].size()>rows[1].size()) cnt=rows[1].size();
    else cnt=rows[0].size();
    int squre=0;
    for( int i = 0; i <cnt; i++ ){
     for( int j = 0; j <cnt; j++ ){
     if((rows[1][j].x-tolerance<=rows[0][i].x)&&(rows[0][i].x<=rows[1][j].x+tolerance))
      squre++;
     }
    }

    /// Show the result
    if(squre > 0)  putText(dst,"Squre", Point(50,50), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1, Scalar (0,0,255), 3, 8,false );
    else  putText(dst,"Rhombic ", Point(50,50), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1, Scalar (0,0,255), 3, 8,false );
    imshow("src,",src);
    imshow("dst",dst);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Here I got some result for your image

> Image 1

[image] [image]

> Image 2

[image] [image]

> Image 3

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Sum all the pixels along the y-direction. You'll get a 1-D signal with a bunch of peaks repeating at some period. Take the x-coordinate of one of these peaks, travel along the image in the y-direction at this x-coordinate, until you find a detected point. Remember the current y-coordinate. Now look at the x-coordinate correspondng to the neighboring peak in the 1-D signal, and the y-coordinate you just remembered. Do you have a detected point here? If yes, it's a square latice. If not, it's a rhombic latice.